# Scroll в LayoutInflater

Tags: android, list, прокрутка

Можно ли как-то отключить Scroll в LayoutInflater?
В моём приложении это очень сильно мешает, т.к. в layout'е реализую ScrollView и у них происходит конфликт(ужасное отображение информации, которое режет глаз).

Comment: Каким образом вы себе это представляете? Инфлейт - парсинг (преобразование) xml-кода разметки в Java-объекты. Ваш вопрос абсолютно не понятен, а в текущем смысле несколько нелеп.

Comment: Ничего в Google не нашел по поводу этого, решил задать вопрос сообществу, может кто-то с этим сталкивался... 
Читал, что такое инфлейт, но когда дают таск переделать фрагмент, который использует инфлейт, да и что бы вся странца сколилась  - остаётся вариант спросить у опытных людей.
Спасибо большое за Ваш замечательный ответ.

Comment: @pavlofff Тогда другой вопрос: Можно ли Инфлейт вывести в LinearLayout?

Comment: ваш вопрос бессмысленен и на него нет ответа. Инфлейт не имеет никакого отношения к включению или отключению скролинга.  Инфлейт нельзя никуда вывести, у него нет визуализации - это создание объектов из xml-кода. Попробуйте  сформулировать вопрос так, чтобы другим тоже было понятна ваша проблема.

Comment: мы формируем инфлейт путём добавления объектов из xml кода и получаем List далее. Тогда какое альтернативное решение данное проблемы Вы можете мне подсказать? Может без использования инфлейта?

Comment: просто забудь про инфлейт, он в любом случае тут не причем

Comment: Могу вам посоветовать избавиться от скроллящихся вложенных элементов, большего из информации в вашем вопросе посоветовать невозможно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LayoutInflater` – это класс, который умеет из содержимого файла макета (layout-файла) создавать `View`. `Inflate` - это просто метод, который это делает - преобразует данные из xml-файла во `View`. 
`LayoutInflater` к прокрутке никакого отношения не имеет, прокрутку обеспечивает либо `ScrollView`, либо `TextView`, либо другие `View`-элементы.

Поэтому ответом на вопрос "Можно ли как-то отключить Scroll в LayoutInflater?" будет "нельзя, так как в LayoutInflater Scroll'а и нет".

А если вам не нужна прокрутка и вы хотите от неё избавиться - просто не используйте `ScrollView`, или замените `ScrollView` на `LinearLayout`.